# redux-thunk fetch parse response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-thunk, facebook-redex

I am new to redux and reactjs and I am trying to fetch some server side data to my code.

This is my thunk fetch:

```
fetch(`/WebApp/Dashboard/CreateAlert`).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is what I see in the console:

[image]

In fiddler I see the response is "Success" as expected.

Is this response valid and how do I parse it, I am a bit confused and there is very little info online.

**EDIT**:

I changed to:

```
fetch(url).
then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    console.log(json);
});
```

And I received the object. Now when I send a complex type(List), I see the bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse a json response:

```
fetch(`/WebApp/Dashboard/CreateAlert`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body for all of the methods you can use to parse the response body.

Comment: now that worked, but when i return a complex type(List<class>) look at my edit

Comment: Are your classes JSON serializable on the server?

Comment: i am returning an mvc JsonResult

Comment: But are your objects being correctly serialized? It looks to be a problem on your server, post the actual JSON string being sent to client if possible.